# Is the Flutter pod in Cocoapods the same as the Flutter SDK?

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

I'm currently working on a project that uses Cocoapods in Flutter 2.2.3 and I'm having Issues with the Flutter pod that in included when I run `pod install`. The version it is giving me is Flutter 1.0.0, even though I'm building the app using flutter 2.2.3.

This is the output I get from running `pod outdated`:

```
Updating spec repo `trunk`
Analyzing dependencies
The color indicates what happens when you run `pod update`
<green>  - Will be updated to the newest version
<blue>   - Will be updated, but not to the newest version because of specified version in Podfile
<red>    - Will not be updated because of specified version in Podfile

The following pod updates are available:
- Firebase 8.3.0 -> (unused) (latest version 8.4.0)
- FirebaseCore 8.3.0 -> 8.3.0 (latest version 8.4.0)
- Flutter 1.0.0 -> 1.0.0 (latest version 2.0.2)
```

This begs the question, is the Flutter pod equivalent and/or overriding the Flutter SDK? I don't think it is but I haven't been able to find any concrete explanation of what the difference between the two are. I tried looking up the Flutter pod on the cocoapods website but the description did not prove helpful at all.

Comment: Cocoapods is for iOS-specific development.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same and came across this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53673

It looks like this is to be expected and doesn't really matter:

> This is expected. The Flutter framework isn't downloaded from CocoaPods; it's copied from your installed Flutter SDK. So it's hard-coded to 1.0 since there's no version resolution for CocoaPods to handle. If you see actual issues related to this, pleas let us know!

Rather confusing given that CocoaPods shows you there's a newer version.